# Opening excel files with system( ) on mac?

Tags: c++, macos, system

I am trying to get my C++ program to open up an existing Excel spreadsheet (along with a bunch of applications), however it keeps returning an error that a file does not exist. I am using the following code:

```
int main(){
    system("open ~/path/file");
    //--open applications using same command--//
}
```

The file is definitely there and this command works to open all the applications, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very probably, the system `/bin/sh` -which by definition is used by [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)- does not expand `~`.

You might try something like

```
 char cmd[256];
 snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "open %s/path/file", getenv("HOME"));
 if (0 != system(cmd)) 
   { fprintf(stderr, "%s failed\n", cmd); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

since *interactive* shells usually expand `~` as `$HOME` and `HOME` is generally an environment variable.

(With C++, you could use `std::string` operations instead of `snprintf`)

My `snprintf` + `system` trick is not at all failproof. If `$HOME` contains spaces or bizarre characters like `;` or `'`, it wont work. And `snprintf` itself might fail (e.g. because `$HOME` is huge).

Of course, you'll better test before that `getenv("HOME")` is not `NULL`. You might use [getpwuid(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3.html) with [getuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html) if `getenv("HOME")` fails by returning `NULL`.

On Linux you probably want `xdg-open` instead of `open`.

Comment: Hey Basile. You suggestion worked perfectly! Thank you for taking the time to help :D